# Creating Apps For the Windows Surface Rt on A Surface Rt

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-rt

I have a windows surface Rt. Which runs on ARM correct . Well I downloaded the Java script to make a app trust me I want to very much .I was planning on spending the $50 and everything . So I got to my desktop it says Application I open it Many times . IT says app can not run on PC get a copy from the Windows App store . I want to create apps Really bad . original surface RT I bought it A couple of Weeks ago . Tell me why I can not crest a ARM Application with a ARM device and if I can Tell me what I can do . I want to be a developer there's not many apps for windows I want to Help make windows a Powerful app store. Visual studio 2013 is the application I downloaded . Is there a way around this. I figured since You cant run X86 apps on Windows RT then it was also the other way Around With ARM . so since I Have ARM I should Be with in the capabilities . To run A System that creates ARM apps (windows/android/apple) or at least Windows RT .

Answer (score 2):

You can't run visual studio on windows RT. There is no workaround.